# Am I basically doing extra work by making my local functions global?

Tags: lua

I read that it is faster and better to keep most of your functions local instead of global.
So I'm doing this:

```
input = require("input")
draw = require("draw")
```

And then in input.lua for example:

```
local tableOfFunctions = {isLetter = isLetter, numpadCheck = numpadCheck, isDigit = isDigit, toUpper = toUpper}
return tableOfFunctions
```

Where isLetter, numpadCheck etc are local functions for that file.
Then I call the functions like so:

```
input.isLetter(key)
```

Now, my question is: Am I reinventing the wheel with this? Aren't global functions stored in a lua table? I do like the way it looks with the input. before the function name, keeps it nice and tidy so I may keep it if it's not a bad coding practise.

Comment: Is `input` not local?

Comment: @GoojajiGreg no because I need it in a different file as well

Comment: I suggest you use `local input = require "input"` in each file that needs those methods.  Avoids globals.  That being said, my current big project in Corona is crawling with globals.  I give those table names a three letter prefix that makes it much **less** likely I'll get a namespace collision.  Still...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reinventing the wheels tailored to your personal needs is centerpiece of lua.
The method you describe is described as a valid one by lua creator himself in his book, [here](http://www.lua.org/pil/15.1.html).

**Everything** in Lua is stored inside a table. The "faster" local function (as well as faster local variables) comes from the way of how globals and upvalues are looked up.
Below the line there's a quote of relevant part of more detailed explanation on speed that happened to occur in on game's forum[.](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=40513&hilit=%20pointer#p240071)
Apart from that, locals are recommended due to cleanness of the code and error proofing.

---

In lua a table is created with {}, this operator reserves a certain amount of memory in the ram for the table. That reserved space stays constant and unmovable, exceptions are implementation details that script writer should not concern himself with.
Any variable you assign table to

```
a={}; 
b={ c={a} }
```

is just a pointer to the table in memory. A pointer takes up either 32 or 64 bits and that's it.
Whenever you pass table around only those 64 bits are copied.
Whenever you query a table in a table:

```
return b.c[1]
```

computer follows the pointer stored in `b`, finds a table object in ram, queries it for key "c", takes pointer to another table, queries that for key "1" then returns the pointer to the table `a`. Just a simple pointer hopping, workload on par with arithmetic.

Every function has associated table `_ENV`, any variable lookup

```
return a
```

is actually a query to that table

```
return _ENV.a
```

If the variable is local, it is stored in `_ENV`.

If there's no variable in `_ENV` with the given name, then global variables are queried, those actually reside in top-level table, the `_ENV` of the root function of the script (it is `require` or `dofile` function that loads and executes the script).
Usually, a link to the global table is stored in any other `_ENV` as `_G`. So the access to a global variable

```
return b
```

is actually something like

```
return _ENV.b or _ENV._G.b
```

Thus it is about 3 pointer jumps instead of 1.
Here is convoluted example that should give you an insight on the amount of work that implies:

```
%RUN THIS IN STANDALONE LUA INTERPRETER
local depth=100--how many pointers will be in a chain
local  q={};--a table
local a={};--a start of pointer chain
local b=a;  -- intermediate variable
for i=1,depth do b.a={} b=b.a end;  --setup chain
local t=os.clock(); 
print(q)  
print(os.clock()-t);--time of previous line execution 
t=os.clock(); --start of pointer chain traversal
b=a 
while b.a do b=b.a end 
print(b) 
print(os.clock()-t)--time of pointer traversal
```

When a pointer chain is about 100 elements, system load fluctuations may actually cause the second time be smaller. The direct access gets notably faster only when you change `depth` to thousands and more intermediate pointers.

Note that, whenever you query uninitialized variable, all 3 jumps are taken.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

Globals **are** stored in the reserved table `_G` (the contents of which you can examine at any time), but it is good programming practice to avoid the use of globals.

Unless there is a very good reason not to, your table `input` should be `local` as well.

From [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html):

> It is good programming style to use local variables whenever possible. Local variables help you avoid cluttering the global environment with unnecessary names. Moreover, the access to local variables is faster than to global ones.

Comment: Yeah, I'll fix that as well.